# Take the time when customer first time register in any system

Tags: sql, row-number

I have some tables in DB:

**C_Master_USER** - that cointains relations between users (ID_USER) and their MasterID (ID_Master) - users that are from difrrent systems but they use f.e. the same email will have the same MasterID

**V_DL_C_USER** - that contains ID_Source and ID_SYS_TYPE for each user

**C_Source** - that contains enitity names for source system

**C_SYS_TYPE** - that contains entity names for system types

and my simple task is to get each MasterID, their RegistratonDate and the Source of first registration in any system

```
SELECT top 50 
MasterID, RegistrationDate, SourceName, SystemName
FROM (
SELECT
    a.ID_MASTER as MasterID, 
    a.DATE_N as RegistrationDate,
    c.Name2 as SourceName,
    d.Name_2 as SystemName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.DATE_N ASC) as RN
FROM C_MASTER_USE a 
join V_DL_C_USER b on a.ID_USER = b.ID 
join c_source c on b.ID_Source = c.ID
join C_SYS_TYPE d on b.ID_SYS_TYPE = d.ID
) t
where RN = 1
```

However, the query results only 1, the latest user in all systems.

```
MasterID    RegistrationDate        SourceName       SystemName

8825938     2020-11-10 08:17:30     Mobile App       Club
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ID_Master ORDER BY a.DATE_N ASC) as RN`

Comment: @Ullas - Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row for each `MasterId` use `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT top 50 
MasterID, RegistrationDate, SourceName, SystemName
FROM (
SELECT
    a.ID_MASTER as MasterID, 
    a.DATE_N as RegistrationDate,
    c.Name2 as SourceName,
    d.Name_2 as SystemName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ID_MASTER ORDER BY a.DATE_N ASC) as RN
FROM C_MASTER_USE a 
join V_DL_C_USER b on a.ID_USER = b.ID 
join c_source c on b.ID_Source = c.ID
join C_SYS_TYPE d on b.ID_SYS_TYPE = d.ID
) t
where RN = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this!